# Location of listener.ora in Oracle 19c?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, tnsnames

I'm new to oracle db. I need to change host of listener to configure local database. But
listener.ora file doesn't exist in C:\app\oracle\product\19.3.0\client_1\network\admin.
By this path I found only:

- sample
- sqlnet.ora
- tnsnames.ora

Thanks!

Comment: The listener.ora file exists on the database server.  It seems unlikely that the database would be running in an Oracle Home that has `client_1` in the path.  If the database is on this server, there will likely be a different Oracle Home for the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you just simply run "lsnrctl status", it should tell you where the listener.ora file is located. Assuming that you truly have a database with a listener running.

For example:

```
[grid@orarac01 ~]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 02-JAN-2024 20:33:17

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                15-OCT-2023 22:29:13
Uptime                    78 days 23 hr. 4 min. 3 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/19.11.0.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/grid/diag/tnslsnr/hqodapd1/listener/alert/log.xml
```